# Assign Data to DropDownList with CascadingDropDown extender

Tags: asp.net-ajax

I have DropDownList with CascadingDropDown extender.

If I want to retrieve data from the database for update to what I should assign the data...... to the dropdownlist or to CascadingDropDown extender and to what properties exactly I should use?

please advice!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're referring to initial data for the control, then you can databind or add list items as you normally would with a DropDownList.  If you're referring to what happens when a user selects a value in one of the lists, this is handled client-side and the data should be returned by a web service method.  You can find the information [here](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx) under the "CascadingDropDown Properties" heading.